# how to install bullet on Indigo in Ubuntu

Tags: ros, bullet, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to build this project, it has `tf2_bullet` which is part of `geometry_experimental` in it and depends on bullet,
So I have been getting this error message whenever I try to do `catkin_make`

```
 add_subdirectory(geometry_experimental/tf2_bullet)
-- checking for module 'bullet'
--   package 'bullet' not found
```

I have done some research and I could not find bullet package. I installed `bullet3` from bullet github but that did not solve the problem
Any help would be appreciated...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220676/how-to-install-bullet-on-indigo-in-ubuntu/) by [Samer](https://answers.ros.org/users/23151/samer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-11-09

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use rosdep for figuring out what package you need to install. Checking out [this yaml file](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml#L348-L383), I see that the you are supposed to install `libbullet-dev` to satisfy the `bullet` requirement.

From the command line you could use a command similar to

```
rosdep install --from-paths WORKSPACE --ignore-src --rosdistro=ROSDISTRO
```

in order to automatically install all system dependencies of all source packages in your WORKSPACE. Note I found the yaml file above with the command

```
rosdep where-defined bullet
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2016-09-14**:
sudo apt-get install libbullet-dev resolved this for me in Rasberry-Pi